# Connecting to Tor network through any Application/Script without installing Tor browser bundle?

Tags: socks

I am planning to develop an application that must use Tor network connection. I am connecting with Tor browser bundle and then using the socket(9050/9150/whatever). Now I want to connect to Tor network directly without Tor browser bundle. Is it possible. If so, please someone help me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible with Vidalia plus Tor combination.
But you need add this to your `torrc` file:

`C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Local Settings\Application Data\Vidalia` and open `torrc` file with Notepad and copy paste this.

```
SocksListenAddress 127.0.0.1
SocksPort 9150
```

Then you can use with another programs with IP 127.0.0.1 and port 9150 as proxy without the Tor browser bundle. But be careful if the program have a bug its can show your real IP. Such as do not transmit properly through the Tor. Works with only TCP protocol but won't work with UDP protocol Like Torrent, and Skype. If you want better and safer condition, use a Proxy management program like Proxyfier or proxycap. This forces the program to always go through with the Tor so there is lower probability to connect to the selected program directly without Tor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use it without browser. For that you must run an application with `-f` key and choose path to your configuration file, as for example, using `tor -f torrc`, where is `torrc` path to your configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

You have several possibilities here. You can

1. deliver an own Tor binary. So your application can either bring a copy of Tor with it or can download a recent copy of it.
2. test if the user has installed it and if it runs. Depending on the test you give a feedback to the user.

When Tor runs, make sure that `SocksPort` in the `torrc` is set. Your application can now connect to the `SocksPort` and use it as SOCKS proxy.

Comment: if I were to choose the first option, do you have any guidelines or documentation on how to create my own binaries for Tor?

Comment: I don't have any guidelines, but I'd suggest to ask the Tor Project and write a mail to <tor-assistants@lists.torproject.org>.